# How to get something random/different, 10 times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, repeat

I will admit I'm stuck on a school project right now.

I have defined functions that will generate random numbers for me, as well as a random operator (+, -, or *).

I have also defined a function that will display a problem using these random numbers.

I have created a program that will generate and display a random problem and ask the user for the solution.  If the user is correct, the program prints 'Correct', and the opposite if the user is incorrect.

I have put all of this inside of a loop that will make it repeat 10 times.  My issue is that I need it to generate 10 different problems instead of the same problem that it randomized the first time, 10 times.

Sorry for the weird wording.

*I am using python but am showing the code here using the CSS viewer because I couldn't get it to display any other way.

Thank you.

```
import random

max = 10

def getOp(max): #generates a random number between 1 and 10
    randNum = random.randint(0,max)
    return randNum
randNum = getOp(max)


def getOperator(): #gets a random operator 
    opValue = random.randint(1,3)
    if opValue == 1:
        operator1 = '+'
    elif opValue == 2:
        operator1 = '-'
    elif opValue == 3:
        operator1 = '*'
    return operator1

operand1 = getOp(max)
operand2 = getOp(max)
operator = getOperator()

def doIt(operand1, operand2, operator): #does the problem so we can verify with user
    if operator == '+':
        answer = operand1 + operand2
    elif operator == '-':
        answer = operand1 - operand2
    elif operator == '*':
        answer = operand1 * operand2
    return answer
answer = doIt(operand1, operand2, operator)

def displayProblem(operand1, operand2, operator): #displays the problem
    print(operand1, operator, operand2, '=')


###My program:
for _ in range(10): #loops the program 10 times
    displayProblem(operand1, operand2, operator)

    userSolution = int(input('Please enter your solution: '))

    if userSolution == doIt(operand1, operand2, operator):
        print('Correct')

    elif userSolution != doIt(operand1, operand2, operator):
        print('Incorrect')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just move your code that is generating the random values into your for loop:

```
for _ in range(10): #loops the program 10 times

    randNum = getOp(max)                
    operand1 = getOp(max)
    operand2 = getOp(max)
    operator = getOperator()
    answer = doIt(operand1, operand2, operator)

    displayProblem(operand1, operand2, operator)

    userSolution = int(input('Please enter your solution: '))

    if userSolution == doIt(operand1, operand2, operator):
        print('Correct')

    elif userSolution != doIt(operand1, operand2, operator):
        print('Incorrect')
```

That way its called before every time you ask the user for input.

Answer (score 1):

You generate the problem and then show it 10 times in the loop:

```
generateProblem()
for _ in range(10):
    showProblem()
```

of course you will get the same problem shown 10 times. To fix this, generate the problem *inside* the loop:

```
for _ in range(10):
    generateProblem()
    showProblem()
```

Answer (score 0):

Crrected Your Code

```
import random

max = 10

def getOp(max): #generates a random number between 1 and 10
    randNum = random.randint(0,max)
    return randNum

def getOperator(): #gets a random operator 
    opValue = random.randint(1,3)
    if opValue == 1:
        operator1 = '+'
    elif opValue == 2:
        operator1 = '-'
    elif opValue == 3:
        operator1 = '*'
    return operator1

def doIt(operand1, operand2, operator): #does the problem so we can verify with user
    if operator == '+':
        answer = operand1 + operand2
    elif operator == '-':
        answer = operand1 - operand2
    elif operator == '*':
        answer = operand1 * operand2
    return answer

def displayProblem(operand1, operand2, operator): #displays the problem
    print(operand1, operator, operand2, '=')


###My program:
for _ in range(10): #loops the program 10 times
  operand1 = getOp(max)
  operand2 = getOp(max)
  operator = getOperator()
  displayProblem(operand1, operand2, operator)

  userSolution = int(input('Please enter your solution: '))

  if userSolution == doIt(operand1, operand2, operator):
    print('Correct')

  elif userSolution != doIt(operand1, operand2, operator):
    print('Incorrect')
```